# Conversion of individual mp4 files to ts yields unexpected playback

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm converting three mp4 files (h264, no audio, each with a duration of three seconds) to the mpeg-ts format like so.

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -c copy 1.ts
ffmpeg -i 2.mp4 -c copy 2.ts
ffmpeg -i 3.mp4 -c copy 3.ts
```

*Please note: I can't combine the mp4 files beforehand. Each one has to be converted individually as shown above since they're being generated by a live recorder.*

Then, I manually created a .m3u8 manifest like this one, so I could play those 3 ts files in sequence:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:3
#EXTINF:3,
1.ts
#EXTINF:3,
2.ts
#EXTINF:3,
3.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

When I run the `ffplay index.m3u8` command:

- 1.ts is played for three seconds as expected;
- 2.ts is played "for a split second" (maybe just a frame);
- 3.ts is played for three seconds as expected.

Can someone explain why 2.ts is shown for such a brief time? When I run `ffmpeg -i 2.ts`, the output is correctly displaying a duration of three seconds.

```
Input #0, mpegts, from '2.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:03.00, start: 1.480000, bitrate: 49 kb/s
```

How can I change my mp4 -> ts conversion commands so that each file can play for their whole duration (i.e. three seconds each)? I'd like to avoid reencoding if possible.

Thank you, I'm adding a [link to the three files and the manifest](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ao4rhSdtDw8rgf8J1vn3MgZ38tfmoA?e=tcUf25) for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out this behavior if affected by the 'start' value which is being set by ffmpeg to '1.480000', as seen in the original question.

By setting a different, proper start value for each file, playback will work fine. This is done via the `-muxdelay` flag which [represents the "maximum demux-decode delay"](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) (i.e. an offset). For some reason, at least in my case, the flag should be provided with half the intended value (e.g 1.5 if the previous video(s) played for 3 seconds)

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -muxdelay 0 -c copy 1.ts
ffmpeg -i 2.mp4 -muxdelay 1.5 -c copy 2.ts
ffmpeg -i 3.mp4 -muxdelay 3.0 -c copy 3.ts
```

Problem's solved but I'm still wondering why only 2.ts was affected by the problem.